# Adding data in sql Table columns

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2012-express

I have this basic WinForms application user interface:

[image]

And I want to add the data both to the DataGridView and the sql table, when the "Gem" button is clicked. I have this following code:

```
private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            con = new SqlConnection();
            con.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Produkt.mdf;Integrated Security=True";
            con.Open();
            //adap = new SqlDataAdapter("select SN, FName as 'Navn', MName as 'Vare nr', LName as 'Antal', Age from Produkt", con);
            string sql = "SELECT Navn, Varenr, Antal, Enhed, Priseksklmoms, Konto FROM ProduktTable";

            adap = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, con);
            ds = new System.Data.DataSet();
            adap.Fill(ds, "ProduktTable");
            dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables["ProduktTable"];

        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error\n" + ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }

    }

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string navn = textBox2.Text;
        int varenr = int.Parse(textBox3.Text);
        float antal = (float)Convert.ToDouble(textBox4.Text);
        string enhed = textBox5.Text;
        string konto = comboBox2.Text;
        float pris = (float)Convert.ToDouble(textBox6.Text);

        dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value = navn;
        dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[1].Value = varenr;

        string StrQuery;

        try
        {

            SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand();
            comm.Connection = con;

            for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                StrQuery = @"INSERT INTO tableName ProduktTable ("
                + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Varenr"].Value + ", "
                + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Antal"].Value + ");";
                comm.CommandText = StrQuery;
                comm.ExecuteNonQuery();                    
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error\n" + ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
```

This is just an example with the purpose for storing the string "navn" and the integer "Varenr" in the DataGridView and the sql. When Im running the application and clicking on the button, following error occurs:

[image]

What's wrong with the procedure ?.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `INSERT INTO tableName ProduktTable` Why is the word `tableName` there? The parser thinks that's your table name, and therefore `ProduktTable` is a syntax error.

Comment: you dont have to mention tableName in insert statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format for an insert name doesn't require the words tableName.  It wants the actual table name.

```
INSERT INTO tableName ProduktTable
```

should be

```
INSERT INTO ProduktTable
```

assuming Produ**K**tTable isn't a typo.

Comment: @marc_s  Okay.  I wasn't sure if it was a typo or not.  The problem should just be teh tableName then.